# Google Play, can i get past purchases on new tablet?

Tags: google-play-store

I am halfway through season 3 of Homeland and bought a new galaxy tablet. It was purchased from the Play Store on my old galaxy tab.

Since I have the same Google account associated with both tablets, is there a way to download the show to the new tablet?

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts, Len! For generic info like this, be welcome to see our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) – which tries to aggregate central questions on this.

Answer (score 2):

When you download a paid or free app on Google Play, the app is connected to your Google Account. This means you can `reinstall` downloaded apps to new or reset devices without purchasing them again.

source : [Reinstall apps & games](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113410?hl=en)

This is About Apk apps.but for Download this, if you can download this again in `Old Device` so you can Copy Downloading Link and Sign In With Purchased Device in New Device.

Also, as this link said : [OIT HelpDesk - Knowledge Base](https://help.utk.edu/kb/index2.php?func=show&e=2157)

> Your purchases are tied to your Google Account and can be installed an
>   unlimited amount of times on any device. So, for example, if you
>   remove "My Favorite Game" to save memory, you can reinstall it at a
>   later date with no charge by simply visiting My Apps. You can also
>   re-install apps from play.google.com from the My Android Apps section.

So, just `Sign in` With *purchased Google Account* in `New Device`, and Find what you want and Downloaded it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually trying to watch a tv series i purchased not an app. I don't have my old tablet with me so I'll try fooling around more with this tonight.

Comment: iknow this is not an app.(as i said).but for this, you need old Account password or download from other Sources.your welcome :).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply yes. As long as you've added the same account the TV show was purchased from to the new device, you're good to go. Open the Play Movies & TV app, swipe in from the left and verify you're using the account that owns them, and tap My Library. And then everything you own will be visible.